# CRON is not updating in Puppet?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, puppet

my current manifest file looks like this,

```
cron { 'Hourly_cron':
         ensure  => 'present',
         command => " /bin/test.py  >> test.log",
         minute => '15',
         user => 'wae_app';
}
```

now i want to update to command => " /bin/test.py  >> test_1.log"..

I have changed but not working ....not updating the CRON ...how to do that

```
cron { 'Hourly_cron':
         ensure  => 'present',
         command => " /bin/test.py  >> test_1.log",
         minute => '15',
         user => 'wae_app';
}
```

Comment: Which command do you exactly run? Because I tried our your example and it works as expected

Comment: Why don't you just use a file-resource and put the target in `/etc/cron.hourly` (files in that directory should be complete executables, scripts and so on, not crontab(5) files).